# How to Display Videos inside RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I have [a blog](http://www.sivrisinema.com) and all posts (i.e. [this post](http://www.sivrisinema.com/aksiyon/universal-soldiers-regeneration/)) have videos in hidden [div](http://www.pastie.org/783097).

I want to display this videos in my [RSS feed.] But not regular blog view.[4](http://feeds.feedburner.com/sivrisinema)

By the way i'm using Wordpress.

How i can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you might want to take a look at RSS enclosures. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_enclosure for more information)

here is a code example:

```
<enclosure url="http://example.com/file.mp3" length="123456789" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

since you seem to run wordpress, you might want to use specific video-blogging plugins.
you can find more information here: http://www.tubetorial.com/wordpress-videoblogging-the-easy-way/

Comment: Ah, i can't find any method for use RSS enclosures in my job. By the way i don't want to use any plugin for this.

Comment: Can you explain RSS enclosures more?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you're using WordPress, I'd recommend setting up a specific category for these video posts (e.g. something like "RSS Only") and then edit your theme files so that category never gets displayed.  See [Exclude Posts From Some Category « The Loop « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category) for details on what you need to change in the theme files.

Comment: I can't understand you. :S I'm attaching videos in posts.

Comment: I understood that. What I'm saying is keep adding your videos to your posts however you've been doing it already, with the exception of putting those video posts in a specific category when you only want them to display in your RSS feed. Then you can edit your WordPress theme to exclude that category from your site. This way the video post will appear in your feed, but not on the site.

Comment: Ok, i understand you. But i want to show video and post together. How i merge them if i use your method?

Comment: I'm not sure we're understanding one another here. From the way your original was written, it sounded to me that:
1. You have a WordPress based blog.
2. You have videos that you want to post to that blog.
3. You did not want those posts containing those videos to appear on the blog.
4. You do want those posts containing those videos to appear in the blog's RSS feed.

If my understanding is wrong, could you please clarify the question?

Comment: 1. True
2. I have posts with videos inside each post but they are hidden. Because i'm showing videos on Fancybox script.
3. I don't want to show videos above reason.
4. I want to show videos in only RSS feed.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: My method would hide the entire post containing the video from the blog & only show it in the RSS feed, which doesn't seem to be what you're trying to accomplish. If you want your posts with videos to display on both your blog & in the RSS feed, but not overload your home page with multiple videos; then I would use the More button/tag (see http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/) & put the videos after the cut.

Comment: Ah, i think i can't explain my problem (again sorry for my bad English). 

I'm hiding videos because, i'm showing it modal window with Fancybox script (this is an example: http://screencast.com/t/YzJiNWU0O). And also i want to show video (of course with flash video player) RSS feed.

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand what you're trying to do. The methods I was trying to explain are not the same thing. Currently your RSS feed appears to be the summary version, you could try changing it to full text (see http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/reading-settings/). If that doesn't bring your videos over into the RSS feeds, then you'll need to read up on RSS enclosures like z3cko mentioned and/or use a plugin to get the videos into your RSS feed.

Comment: It was already full text on Wordpress settings. Also i'm serving RSS feeds through Feedburner. I will look on RSS enclosures. Thanks for everything.